# Open Graph Tags and Facebook Like Button

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

A very basic question

I looking to use the "Like" button that is built into the Open Graph - 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/

According to the documentation I must supply the Object that is to be "Liked" with the following Object Properties

I had put images in here but was told I dont have enough reputation to do so

Object Properties:
TitleString
DescriptionString
ImageImage[]
URLURL

My question is, am I supposed to use og type tags for the "like" object properties that are used for the properties of other timeline objects (see image below for the image of the for the properties of of another object I am creating) or does this object  just use standard meta tags?

Properties:
NameTypeSetting
og:urlURLRequired
og:titleStringRequired
og:imageImage[]Required
og:descriptionStringRequired
Show Optional Properties

They way I have the Like button set up on my site currently, Facebook seems to pull data from Og tags and non og tags.  For example, currently my Like button currently pulls information from my description metatag that is not associated with any sort of og property - og:description is not being used at all.

Any input would be appreciated

Comment: What are the "following properties"?

Comment: Can you post your code or the URL where your code lives? Also, have you tried using the debugger? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/